# PHP Regex match word or group of words in all capital letters

Tags: php, regex

How can I use regex to match a word or groups of words that are in all capital letters?

I believe I've solved the problem half way, although it may not be the right way.

I am trying to catch one word in all caps, or two or three - basically if they're in succession I want them captured as a group, not as each word itself.

e.g.:
"HAPPY BIRTHDAY TOMMY" wouldn't match and return `[0] -> HAPPY, [1] -> BIRTHDAY, [2] -> TOMMY`, but the whole group, such as `[0] -> HAPPY BIRTHDAY TOMMY`.

The code I'm using below matches "HAPPY BIRTHDAY" together, or just "TOMMY", but not everything together.

```
[A-Z]{1,}\s[A-Z]{1,}|\b[A-Z]{1,}\b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(?=[A-Z])([A-Z\s]+)
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/fNWdw)

Comment: That does pick up the trailing whitespace, but that may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Just for future reference, to ignore the whitespace use the following regex:
(?=[A-Z])([A-Z]+)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I fully understand what you need, but in order to group you have to use parenthesis (). try this:

```
([A-Z]+)\b([A-Z]+)\b([A-Z]+)\b
```

This should capture three consecutive all-caps words.

Comment: You don't match the whitespace between the words. A word boundary isn't matching them.

Comment: Group zero is always the full match of the expression. For HAPPY BIRTHDAY TOMMY it will return [0]=>HAPPY BIRTHDAY TOMMY [1]=>HAPPY [2]=>BIRTHDAY [3]=>TOMMY

Comment: @stema - Looking at the expected result in Ryan's post, the boundaries shouldn't be captured.

Comment: Boundaries aren't captured at all. The thing is your expressions will not match the sentence "HAPPY BIRTHDAY TOMMY". In fact it will never match anything. You are checking for a letter, then a word boundary, but then there should be again a letter ==> that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the trick `/([A-Z]\s?)+/`. This should catch sequences like HAPPY BIRTHDAY TOMMY as a set and HAPPY BIRTHDAY tommy BOY as two sets ('HAPPY BIRTHDAY' and 'BOY').

Comment: This will capture all uppercase letters in a sentence see [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v5gm)

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
$str = "My test sentence HAPPY BIRTHDAY TOMMY this is lower case an UPPERCASE more lowercase";
if (preg_match_all('/\\b(?=[A-Z])[A-Z ]+(?=\\W)/',$str,$match)) {                      
    var_dump($match[0]);
}
```

result is

> array(2) { [0]=> string(20) "HAPPY BIRTHDAY TOMMY" [1](http://regexr.com?2v5gp)=> string(9) "UPPERCASE" }

The usage of the lookahead at the end ensures that there is no whitespace included at the end, as it would happen if a word boundary is used and there is another word following.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v5gp)